# Cannot connect Samsung device in fastboot

Tags: adb, samsung, fastboot

I am attempting to use fastboot on an old Samsung Galaxy A01. It is a learning exercise for unlocking. Based on [this](https://www.getdroidtips.com/how-to-unlock-bootloader-on-samsung-galaxy-phones/#Supported-Samsung-Devices), the device should support using fastboot. I got it off a Samsung forum. I am running on a Windows 11 machine.

I can run

```
$ .\adb.exe -d devices
List of devices attached
R9HN*******     device
```

Which allows me to run `.\adb.exe reboot bootloader` which reboots the device into fastboot. The issue I cannot seem to solve is getting the drivers to work at this point.

I run `.\fastboot.exe devices` and nothing shows up. I checked my device management and I can see it under `Ports (COM & LPT) > USB Serial Device (COM9)` I have added the Samsung drivers from [here](https://developer.samsung.com/mobile/android-usb-driver.html) and it will change to those. Each time though, I get a warning triangle on the device and it says.

> This device cannot start. (Code 10)
>
> {Operation Failed}
> The requested operation was unsuccessful.

I have also manually attempted to use the Android drivers [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb) but it says they are not the correct arch?

Any suggestion on how to get fastboot drivers for this device to work?

Comment: Note that there are a lot of generated pages out there that are just "click traps" without actually containing valid information about Android rooting. The Samsung devices I had contact did not had to be unlocked via fastboot, usually Samsung devices don't have  a real fastboot mode at all. You enable OEM unlock and then flash what you want to flash using Odin/Heimdall. On next reboot the phone then asks if it should be unlocked. The COM9 you get is a good indicator as Windows never detects a fastboot device as a COM device. So you are most likely in DFU mode because there is no fastboot.

Comment: @Robert just to confirm I can do `.\adb.exe reboot bootloader` which reboots the device to a screen that says fastboot. Does that not matter and I should look into `Odin/Heimdall`? I saw those before as well but those looked more like that "click traps".

Comment: I would recommend to search xda-dev forum for your device and root. You will get some topics and the few I have checked they always use Odin/Heimdall.

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. As mentioned by Robert, Samsung devices don't have Fastboot mode (it's a stub/not working). Instead, they have Download mode, which can only be operated with Odin/Heimdall.